# Workflow Rule Execution criteria

Tags: workflow, field-update

I have 4 WF rule which are firing on different criteria. 
The criteria is like

- 1 WF will fire on Stage1,
- 2nd WF will fire on Stage2,
- 3rd WF will fire on Stage3
- 4th WF will fire on Stage4.
  1st WF will update Stage1 to Stage2 like this others will also update.

They all are working fine when meeting criteria individually. 
But when I'm creating or Editing any record meeting criteria of 1st WF, it is firing till 2nd WF instead of all 4. It is firing only first 2.

Is there any limit of WF rule firing on editing record like only 2 WF rule can fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a limit of 5 recursions (e.g. five successive field updates that cause further rule evaluation), and a limit of 50 active workflow rules per object. In order for, e.g. WF2 to trigger WF3, it must cause the condition for WF3 to be triggered (e.g. changing the Stage again), *and* it must specify "re-evaluate workflow rules" option. Most likely, WF2 does not currently have that setting enabled, so you'll want to check.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox it fixed the issue. But my first WF also does not have "re-evaluate workflow rules" checkbox true and it was still working.

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper Without seeing your specific criteria, I suspect that WF2 was meeting the conditions upon initial entry. The re-evaluate option must be used for rules to be considered a second time.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a limit. With what you describe, I suggest you combine these using the CASE statement, particularly since they're all on Stage.